# Expanpandable ListView Crashes when deleting last Child in group is expanded

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, expandablelistview

I have an issue when I am deleting a Child from Item from a group in a Expandable List View. The issue is when my Group is expanded and I delete the child "getChildView" is being called when I 
execute "notifyDataSetChanged" on my ListView adapter. I am accessing an array whose size is now zero and get an Out Of Bounds exception. I would assume that the Expandable Listview would automatically delete the view because "getChildrenCount" returns 0. If the group is collapsed this issue is not seen. The List never displays the child view because there are no more children.

My question is How do you delete the last child on a expanded group in an expandable ListView

Here is an example of my code. Understand that the condition is that the group is expanded and I have delete all of the children and this function is still being called.

```
    // This Function used to inflate child rows view
    @Override
    public View getChildView(
        int groupPosition,
        int childPosition,
        boolean isLastChild, 
        View convertView,
        ViewGroup parentView)
    {
        Trade t = objArray[groupPosition];

        View childView = convertView;
        if( childView == null )
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(client);
            childView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_textview, parentView, false);
            ChildViewHolder childViewHolder = new ChildViewHolder();

            childViewHolder.itemTextView = (TextView)childView.findViewById(R.id.itemTextView);
            childView.setTag(childViewHolder);
        }

        ChildViewHolder childViewHolder = (ChildViewHolder)childView.getTag();

        childViewHolder.itemTextView.setText("Term: " + t.getTradeTerms().get(childPosition));
        return childView;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition)
    {
        return objArray[groupPosition].getTradeTerms().size();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

please see below code i hope this is very help full.

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;
 List<String> listDataHeader;

// Listview on child click listener
    expListView.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v,
                int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

          listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).remove(childPosition);
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

            return false;
        }
    });
```

Comment: No this wont help. I am removing the data from another window via the List I passed into the adapter. I call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() which causes the Exp. List View to re-configure. Try this experiment. Delete a child in a group which is expanded. Your getChildView will get call. How do you handle this event when the child data has been deleted already.

Comment: if you remove data from another activity so use public array list and after you use adatpter.notifyDataSetChaged();